# Counterexample in Lusin's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> **2.24 Lusin's Theorem**<sup>[1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqMk4.jpg)</sup> Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu(A) < \infty$, $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin A$, and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $g \in C_c(X)$ such that
>
> $$ \mu(\{x : f(x) \neq g(x) \}) < \epsilon.$$

**Question.** If  $\mu (A) = \infty$ in Lusin's theorem stated above, then does there exist $g \in C_c(X)$ such that

$$\mu (\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}) < \epsilon \quad ?$$

---

Notation: Here $C_c(X)$ set of all complex valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact support and $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space.

I want to proceed by examples. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$. Take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ with the counting measure. So, $\mu (\mathbb{Q}) = \infty$.  Let $f(x) = 0 $ when $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $x$ when $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Clearly $f$ is a measurable. So, clearly the condition of $f$ in theorem is satisfied.

So, $f$ is nowhere continuous.  Let $0< \epsilon < 1$. Now by the sake of contradiction assume that let $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$\mu (\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}) < \epsilon$$ holds.

So,  for the counting measure $\mu (\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}) < \epsilon$ implies    the set $\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is empty set. So, $f = g $ for all $x$. Hence, $f$ is itself a continuous function. So, we found a contradiction, as $f$ is not continuous.

Is it correct?

Comment: First of all, how are the conditions satisfied if $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=\infty$? Also, $g$ depends on $\epsilon$, this is not always the same $g$. So your conclusion about $f=g$ almost everywhere is wrong.

Comment: @Mark  Thanks for your correction. I have edited. Can you please check now?